# Make template into a form

Tags: arcgis-pro, tasks

I work in an office where I am one of the few GIS specialists. I hope to make an ArcGIS Pro template more into a form to allow inexperienced users to answer a few questions that pop up, and the template will then auto-fill the queries. EX. I have a map showing the United States outlines. I want the inexperienced user to answer which state they want to focus on, and their answer should be a query of a layer so only the single state shows up.

Is there a way to do this so they don't have to open the layer properties and then form the query themselves?

Comment: Have you explored Tasks in Arcpro?